# Freeswitch IVR pressed one Digit and bridge on 2 param actions

Tags: freeswitch, freepbx, fusionpbx

In My Freeswitch IVR have an entry like,

```
<entry action="menu-exec-app" digits="1" param="voicemail default $${domain} 8000"/>
```

here I want to also go to `"curl http://www.google.com"` at the same digit pressed 1 like,

```
<entry action="menu-exec-app" digits="1"
 param="voicemail default $${domain} 8000 AND curl http://www.google.com"/>
```

Is it possible or not? If possible how do we implement it?

Comment: How it relate to freepbx?

Comment: @arheops freepbx is also a product based on Freeswitch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use execute_extension, to run multiple applications with a single digit press. 
Like this,

```
<entry action="menu-exec-app"
           digits="1"
           param="execute_extension voicemail:'default $${domain} 8000',curl:'http://www.google.com' inline"/>
```

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools:+IVR+Menu#mod_dptools:IVRMenu-Howtorunseveralappswithonedigit